# Why DatePicker crash when Date becomes nil?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I don't understand why this is crashing. I'm using ios14 and XCode 12.0 beta 4.
If I delete the DatePicker it works right. Any ideas?

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var myDate: Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            if let selection = Binding<Date>($myDate) {
                DatePicker("myDate", selection: selection)
                Button("Delete myDate") {
                    myDate = nil
                }
            } else {
                Button("Add myDate") {
                    myDate = Date()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI DatePicker Binding optional Date, valid nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272801/swiftui-datepicker-binding-optional-date-valid-nil)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very strange...

`Binding<Date>($myDate)` returns a binding with a date set to "Jan 1, 2001 at 1:00 AM".

This behavior seems to happen when the `State` is a `Date` (with a `String`, it returns `nil` as expected):

```swift
struct A {
    @State var date: Date? = nil
    @State var str: String? = nil

    var dateBinding: Binding<Date>? {
        Binding($date)
    }

    var stringBinding: Binding<String>? {
        Binding($str)
    }
}

A().dateBinding // not nil
A().dateBinding!.wrappedValue // "Jan 1, 2001 at 1:00 AM"

A().stringBinding // nil
```

And it seems to work fine without using property wrappers:

```swift
let stateDate = State<Date?>(initialValue: nil)
Binding<Date>(stateDate.projectedValue) // nil
```

This is probably an issue of Xcode 12 beta.

**Edit:**

This seems to be related to the state alone:

```swift
struct A {
    @State var date1: Date? = nil
}
A().date1 // Jan 1, 2001 at 1:00 AM"

State<Date?>(initialValue: nil).wrappedValue // nil
```